# Vega-lite areas with a diagonal stripe pattern

Tags: css, vega-lite

I'm using Vega-lite to create several plots. Some of them should have a diagonal pattern fill, like this:

[image]

I though of using a css gradient fill to accomplish this. Then I can easily parameterize it and don't have to deal with images. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/) shows how to do that...

[image]

Now the `gradient` option in `mark.color` gets close, but the pattern doesn't repeat...

[image]

That experiment can be [edited online](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUAZ1QTRA4M5bBwhKKAhiEABfJUx1JFkIADM2dQQ0AG1QXJpBTDh1KOUghgRKCABPBCY2QQBebrN9AHk+-TM0gF0lZHV7NFBMZpw4KKR1OBQlYVkF0JAoDoLapfsyZbh5dO3dmq2ADwBGNAAGJWa71BulK4AmNDeQZq-UR4gI5IZQ0E6YKLrFY1JQ2Nh4EqgNi5XIQOAQgFKHaCPboADuMBEaQUSJRaIx90oP2xuJABKJ6VJqPRDypWIu+0mRzgJ2JTPJrI+7Jxl0CXOOpxGqTOJx2oNkZGmICuSvKcEEyn2VQCs3mUSqCBwBSQkTOzVVYI1UWcNFcOrmmxAAEcGNkdMEdKQ0tKgA)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pattern fills are not currently supported.

https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1372

If you're plotting in PowerBI,  you can use Deneb which adds pattern fills to VL.